# Best way to convert array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am developing a react app, and I am getting the below array from a api call.

```
var arrayLike ={ 
         "2020-W1": [
         { 
            "type": "TAX_REFUND_IN_INT", 
            "net_amount_base": "500001"
         },
         { 
            "type": "TAX_REFUNDIN_IN_EXT", 
            "net_amount_base": "500002"
         }
      ],
      "2020-W2": [
         { 
            "type": "RENTAL_LEASING_INCOME_IN_INT", 
            "net_amount_base": "5000"
         },
         { 
            "type": "DIVIDENTS_INCOME_IN_INT", 
            "net_amount_base": "15000"
         },
         { 
            "type": "LICENCE_INCOME_IN_EXT", 
            "net_amount_base": "10000"
         },
         { 
            "type": "OTHER_INCOME_IN_EXT", 
            "net_amount_base": "1000"
         } 
      ] 
   }
```

I want to convert this array like below:

```
var new_arr =  var new_arr =  [{
            year_week: '2020-W1',
            TAX_REFUND_IN_INT: '1000',
            TAX_REFUNDIN_IN_EXT: '300' 
          },
          {
            year_week: '2020-W2',
            RENTAL_LEASING_INCOME_IN_INT: '2000',
            DIVIDENTS_INCOME_IN_INT: '15000',
            LICENCE_INCOME_IN_EXT: '10000',
            OTHER_INCOME_IN_EXT: '1000' 
          } ]
```

Can someone please help me how to do this? I can change the source  array also if required since I have control over the API.Please let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: The input array is not valid

Comment: could you please tell what is wrong. I will correct that

Comment: @NabajitRoy `var actual arr`, `["2020-W1" :{`, `int_ext: "INT""`, `var new_arr =  var new_arr =  [{`

Comment: @NabajitRoy See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to check what an array is. Looking at your structure I believe it is an object and you are messing up the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over the array, and pull out the parts that you want. If your incoming data is in `actual_arr`

```
var actual_arr = {
  "2020-W1" :{
  0: {site_id: "004", year_week: "2020-W1", type: "RENTAL_LEASING_INCOME", in_out: "IN", int_ext: "INT","amount" :1000},
  1: {site_id: "004", year_week: "2020-W1", type: "DIVIDENTS_INCOME", in_out: "IN", int_ext: "INT","amount" :300},
  2: {site_id: "004", year_week: "2020-W1", type: "LICENCE_INCOME", in_out: "IN", int_ext: "INT","amount" :20},
  3: {site_id: "004", year_week: "2020-W1", type: "OTHER_INCOME", in_out: "IN", int_ext: "INT","amount" :100 },
  },
 }



const new_arr = Object.keys(actual_arr).map(key=> {
  // Build an object to receive the values
  const object = {year_week: key}
   Object.keys(actual_arr[key]).forEach(ix => {
     const income_name = actual_arr[key][ix].type
     const income_amount = actual_arr[key][ix].amount
      object[income_name] = income_amount
  })
  return object
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arrayLike = {
  "2020-W1": [{
      "type": "TAX_REFUND_IN_INT",
      "net_amount_base": "500001"
    },
    {
      "type": "TAX_REFUNDIN_IN_EXT",
      "net_amount_base": "500002"
    }
  ],
  "2020-W2": [{
      "type": "RENTAL_LEASING_INCOME_IN_INT",
      "net_amount_base": "5000"
    },
    {
      "type": "DIVIDENTS_INCOME_IN_INT",
      "net_amount_base": "15000"
    },
    {
      "type": "LICENCE_INCOME_IN_EXT",
      "net_amount_base": "10000"
    },
    {
      "type": "OTHER_INCOME_IN_EXT",
      "net_amount_base": "1000"
    }
  ]
}

let newArray = []
Object.values(arrayLike).forEach((arr, index) => {
  let newObj = {}
  newObj['yearWeek'] = Object.keys(arrayLike)[index]
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    newObj[`${item.type}`] = item.net_amount_base
  })

  newArray.push(newObj)
})

console.log(newArray)
```

Edit: Updated with a snippet!

Answer (score 0):

You could try some array manipulation with `map`, `reduce`.

Below snippet could help

```js
const arr = {
  "2020-W1": {
    0: { site_id: "004", year_week: "2020-W1", type: "RENTAL_LEASING_INCOME", in_out: "IN", int_ext: "INT", amount: 1000 },
    1: { site_id: "004", year_week: "2020-W1", type: "DIVIDENTS_INCOME", in_out: "IN", int_ext: "INT", amount: 300 },
    2: { site_id: "004", year_week: "2020-W1", type: "LICENCE_INCOME", in_out: "IN", int_ext: "INT", amount: 20 },
    3: { site_id: "004", year_week: "2020-W1", type: "OTHER_INCOME", in_out: "IN", int_ext: "INT", amount: 100 },
  },
  "2020-W2": {
    0: { site_id: "004", year_week: "2020-W2", type: "RENTAL_LEASING_INCOME", in_out: "IN", int_ext: "INT", amount: 2000 },
    1: { site_id: "004", year_week: "2020-W2", type: "DIVIDENTS_INCOME", in_out: "IN", int_ext: "INT", amount: 400 },
    2: { site_id: "004", year_week: "2020-W2", type: "LICENCE_INCOME", in_out: "IN", int_ext: "INT", amount: 2000 },
    3: { site_id: "004", year_week: "2020-W2", type: "OTHER_INCOME", in_out: "IN", int_ext: "INT", amount: 5000 },
  },
  "2020-W3": {
    0: { site_id: "004", year_week: "2020-W3", type: "RENTAL_LEASING_INCOME", in_out: "IN", int_ext: "INT", amount: 1000 },
    1: { site_id: "004", year_week: "2020-W3", type: "DIVIDENTS_INCOME", in_out: "IN", int_ext: "INT", amount: 2000 },
    2: { site_id: "004", year_week: "2020-W3", type: "LICENCE_INCOME", in_out: "IN", int_ext: "INT", amount: 3000 },
    3: { site_id: "004", year_week: "2020-W3", type: "OTHER_INCOME", in_out: "IN", int_ext: "INT", amount: 4000 },
  },
}

const res = Object.keys(arr).map((year_week) => {
  const typeAmounts = Object.keys(arr[year_week]).reduce(
    (acc, index) => ({
      ...acc,
      [arr[year_week][index].type]: arr[year_week][index].amount,
    }),
    {}
  )
  return {
    year_week,
    ...typeAmounts,
  }
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this gives the exact format that you are looking for (an Array of Objects).

I used Set() in this case to remove duplicates and then used the spread operator (...) to turn it back into an array with all the unique objects.
There are ways to do the same thing with .reduce() and .filter() as well.
Here are some resources that may be helpful.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

```js
let arrayLike = {
    "2020-W1": [{
            "type": "TAX_REFUND_IN_INT",
            "net_amount_base": "500001"
        },
        {
            "type": "TAX_REFUNDIN_IN_EXT",
            "net_amount_base": "500002"
        }
    ],
    "2020-W2": [{
            "type": "RENTAL_LEASING_INCOME_IN_INT",
            "net_amount_base": "5000"
        },
        {
            "type": "DIVIDENTS_INCOME_IN_INT",
            "net_amount_base": "15000"
        },
        {
            "type": "LICENCE_INCOME_IN_EXT",
            "net_amount_base": "10000"
        },
        {
            "type": "OTHER_INCOME_IN_EXT",
            "net_amount_base": "1000"
        }
    ]
}

function solveProblem(arrayLike) {
    let final_array = []
    let newObjectOne = {}
    let newObjectTwo = {}
    for (i in arrayLike) {
        for (z in i) {
            if (i === "2020-W1") {
                if (arrayLike[i][z] !== undefined) {
                    newObjectOne["year_week"] = "2020-W1",
                        newObjectOne[arrayLike[i][z].type] = arrayLike[i][z].net_amount_base
                    final_array.push(newObjectOne)
                }
            }
            if (i === "2020-W2") {
                if (arrayLike[i][z] !== undefined) {
                    newObjectTwo["year_week"] = "2020-W2",
                        newObjectTwo[arrayLike[i][z].type] = arrayLike[i][z].net_amount_base

                    final_array.push(newObjectTwo)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    let unqiueItemsArr = new Set(final_array)
    return [...unqiueItemsArr]
}
//console.log(solveProblem(arrayLike)) to see new array of objects
console.log(solveProblem(arrayLike))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.entreis`, `map`, `Object.fromEntries` to convert.

```js
const convert = data => Object.entries(data).map(([year_week, arr]) => ({
  year_week,
  ...Object.fromEntries(arr.map(Object.values)),
}));

var arrayLike = {
  "2020-W1": [
    {
      type: "TAX_REFUND_IN_INT",
      net_amount_base: "500001",
    },
    {
      type: "TAX_REFUNDIN_IN_EXT",
      net_amount_base: "500002",
    },
  ],
  "2020-W2": [
    {
      type: "RENTAL_LEASING_INCOME_IN_INT",
      net_amount_base: "5000",
    },
    {
      type: "DIVIDENTS_INCOME_IN_INT",
      net_amount_base: "15000",
    },
    {
      type: "LICENCE_INCOME_IN_EXT",
      net_amount_base: "10000",
    },
    {
      type: "OTHER_INCOME_IN_EXT",
      net_amount_base: "1000",
    },
  ],
};



console.log(convert(arrayLike));
```